# Has Aquaman ever been a merman?

Tags: dc, aquaman, mermaids

I see from looking around that Aquaman has existed with and fought mermaids and mermen.

Is there any incarnation of Aquaman where he was a merman, was turned into a merman, or had the ability to become a merman?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question; I know almost nothing about this mythos.

Comment: It's an incredibly popular topic on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aquaman/comments/1q01i7/anyone_else_ever_wonder_what_aquaman_would_look/?)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Justice Leage of America 119 (published in 1975), Aquaman is turned into a merman by alien invaders. He remains trapped in this form until the following issue. [image]

Comment: I knew it had to happen somewhere

Comment: Finally, a correct answer..

Comment: Great answer, good job on getting literally as much reputation from one answer as I have gotten in months lol.

Comment: Moments like this is why it took so long for Aquaman to get respect

Answer (score 2):

One answer is that he is a merman, just not with the appearance you are thinking of.
However, I know what you mean.

In the current continuity, they haven't appeared, but in the post crisis world, all the residents of Tritonis (which are the cities near or in Atlantis) appeared as classic mer-people. In the image below you see Iqula, who is the protector of Tritonis.

To distinguish, Aquaman is an Atlantean, and therefore a separate race in the Post-Crisis world (but not in current continuity).

[image: A cover from Aquaman 4 in 1991]

Comment: But in that image, Aquaman looks like normal.. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: No, I must have misread the question when I went to answer it. I added another sentence to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

## The answer seems to be "no".

While Atlantis seems to have no shortage of merpeople, Aquaman does not seem to have ever been one of them.

I can find no imagery or references to suggest that Aquaman ever had the telling merman physiology.

Even Superman and Batman have been mermen at one point or another:

[image][image]

But not Arthur Curry.

DC Comics' official [profile of Aquaman](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/aquaman) makes no reference to Aquaman as a merman either.

Comment: Super-Merman! Wow!